# React-countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Okay, so I have an online auction react-app that is receiving the following data from an API,

```
"auction": {
                    "id": 210,
                    "name": "Auction Dev Test",
                    "startDate": "2021-11-03",
                    "startTime": "11:41:00",
                    "status": "COMPLETED",
                    "endDate": "2021-11-03",
                    "endTime": "20:00:00"
            }
```

So now what I want, using CLASS Components, I want to display a countdown timer displaying days:hrs:mins:sec getting values from **auction.startDate, auction.startTime, and auction.endDate, auction.endTime**.

I recently used Countdown from 'react-countdown' but it requires the data to be in milliseconds. Source https://npm.io/package/react-countdown

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `<Countdown date={new Date(\`${auction.endDate}T${auction.endTime}\`).getTime()} />`

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan, it works!